# Is there any way to use colspan with GridView.builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I'm using GridView.builder and looking for a way to add colspan for a specific child to take the full width.
In the below example, I have a 2-column GridView which each column represents a product, but whenever user reaches to the end of the list, I want to show a loading indicator, which in this case it is shown in the first column on the left. I want the `Center` widget to take 2 columns space like `colspan=2` and show the loading indicator in the center.

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: products.length + 1,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8),
    ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index >= products.length) {
       return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return ProductListItem(product: products[index]);
  },
),
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SurajKhanal not yet.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions here:

1, use a `CustomScrollView` with `SliverList` and `SliverGrid` together.
ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM
[CustomScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMywc.png)

2, use the plugin `flutter_staggered_grid_view`.
ref: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view
[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Nrs.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).